# How can I correct this int to boolean error?

Tags: java

Sorry I am having a mental block, can anyone see why I get the 'cannot convert from int to boolean' error message. Much appreciated

```
public static void main (String[]args) {
  int max=10;
  int sum=0;
  int count=0;
  for(int counter=0;counter=max-4;counter++) {
    sum=max-4;
    count=max-3;
    for(sum=3;sum<5;sum++) {
      if(count==0 && max>0){
        System.out.println("Hello");
      } else if (count<4) {
        System.out.println("Go for it");
      } else {
        System.out.println("OK");
      } 
    }
  }
  sum=sum+count;
  System.out.println("Total = "+sum);
  System.out.println("Max = "+count);
}
```

I feel like I have checked using the '==' for the if condition.

Comment: Seems likely to be a simple typographic error, given that the second `for` loop was constructed correctly. Voting to close as it seems unlikely to help others.

Comment: Ok thanks! I  missed that.Really appreciate the fast response. Do you know if I changed counter to count it's value would be 8 at the end of the program and not 7?

Comment: In general, compiler and exception messages indicate the exact line that the problem exists or originates from.

Answer (score 3):

`=` is assignment, you need a comparison in the second term of your loop.

```
for(int counter=0;counter=max-4;counter++) {
```

should be

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < max - 4; counter++) {
```

(white space added, but note `<` is a comparison... perhaps you wanted `<=`).

Answer (score 1):

In case of Java, the syntax of for loop is

```
for(initialization; Boolean_expression; update) {
    // Statements
}
```

1) The initialization part executes only once when the flow enters the for loop for the first time

2) Next, the boolean expression is resolved according to the condition

3) Then next the update statement is resolved and after execution of the body of the for loop again the flow goes to the boolean expression and then update statement and the flow goes on.

So, In your program instead of a boolean expression, you have used an assignment operator which turns out to be 6 which is not 0 or 1. Boolean expression are `true = 1` and `false = 0`. Hence the integer 6 cannot be converted to boolean. So, you can go with `counter < max-4`

Comment: Ok thanks! I missed that.Really appreciate the fast response. Do you know why, if I were to change counter to count it's value would be 8 at the end of the program and not 7?

Comment: At the end of the code I get the value of count to be 8  System.out.println("Max = "+count); if I was to swap the 'for' loop variable 'counter' with 'count the value is 8 and not 7. I've no idea why?!

Comment: That is because the for loop executes only once and the count = 7 at the end of for loop. But, after that, the count becomes 8 when it reaches the update statement of for loop so count = 8 and again it checks the 2nd statement that is count <  max-4 which becomes false and therefore it comes out of the for loop and prints the count value as 8.